# dataSource is updated but Listview is not refreshed in react-native after componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: listview, react-native

I'm trying to refresh listview when componentWillReceiveProps executes. It seems dataSource is updated after fetching ( I put console.log(this.state.dataSource) in the render() and it changes according to the endpoint's current status. )

However, the ListView stays as same. I was wondering why and was suspicious of dataSource. So I ended up making string object to print out the dataSource in the render(). `var str = JSON.stringify(this.state.dataSource._dataBlob.s1);`

And `<View><Text>{str}</Text>`

The above part changes when componentWillReceiveProps() executed. However, the listview stays as same. I'm having no clue why this happens.

Here is the snippet of my code.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(){
    var query = ApiUrl.urlForWeekInfo(this.state.email);
    console.log(query);
    this._executeQuery(query,3);
  }


  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    var dataSource = new ListView.DataSource(
      {rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1.guid !== r2.guid});

      this.state = {
      isLoading: false,
      ...
      first_name: this.props.first_name,
      email: this.props.email,
      dataSource: dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.props.listings)      
    };
  }
..

_executeQuery(query,i) {

    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    fetch(query)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => this._handleResponse(json.response,i))
      .catch(error =>
         this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          message: 'Something bad happened ' + error
    }));
  }

  _handleResponse(response,i) {
    this.setState({ isLoading: false , message: '' });
    if (response.application_response_code.substr(0, 1) === '1') {
      if(i==1){
        this.props.navigator.push({
          title: 'Apply',
          component: Apply,
          passProps: {listings: response.listings, times: response.timetable, week_num: this.state.week_num}
        });
      } else if (i==3){

        var output = response.listings;
        this.setState({
          dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(output)
        });

        console.log(response.listings);
        this.forceUpdate();

      }
    } else {
    }
  }

render() {

    console.log(this.state.dataSource._dataBlob.s1);

    var str = JSON.stringify(this.state.dataSource._dataBlob.s1);
    var listviewsource = this.state.dataSource;

    return (

    <View style={[this.border('red'), styles.container_top]}>
      <View style={[this.border('black'), styles.container_top_buttons]} >

        <ListView
          dataSource={listviewsource}
          renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}/> 

      </View>      
      {spinner}
      <View>
      <Text>{str}</Text>
      </View>

    </View>




        );
        }}
```

Please share any idea or experience you might have.

---

**I ended up finding a solution for this issue:**

```
var array = response.listings;
    var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    //=> call another ds variable.

    this.setState({
      rawData: array,
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(response.listings)
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct method to update rows to your ListView. There is not much documentation on `ListView.DataSource` out there. So here it goes-

***If you want to add/append/prepend/update/delete rows from a ListView, all you have to do is just update the dataSource and call cloneWithRows() in setState.***

For eg. I want to fetch data from a URL. Each time I hit "Load more", I append new rows to my data source.

```
getInitialState: function(){
    return {
        rawData: [],
        dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
          rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2
        }),
        loaded: false,
        page: 1,
    }
},
```

At the very first time, I call this function in ComponentDidMount() which populates my ListView with initial data and "page"=1 in the state.

```
  reloadData: function(){
    this.setState({ loaded: false, rawData: [], page: 1 });

    API.getUpcomingMovies(this.state.page)
      .then((data) => {
          this.setState({
            rawData: this.state.rawData.concat(data),
            dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.state.rawData.concat(data)),
            loaded: true,
          });
      });
  },
```

And every time I tap on "load more" to get JSON from the API, I call the following function. Where "page" is incremented every time I hit "load more".

```
fetchData: function(){

    this.setState({ loaded: false, page: this.state.page+1 });

    API.getUpcomingMovies(this.state.page)
        .then((data) => {
            this.setState({
              rawData: this.state.rawData.concat(data),
              dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.state.rawData.concat(data)),
              loaded: true,
            });
        });
  },
```

As you can see, I am concatenating my rawData[] (which is a simple array holding JSON objects). If you want to prepend new data to your rawData, you can do something like this-

```
this.setState({
    rawData: data.concat(this.state.rawData)
)}
```

Comment: In my case, I don't have to concatenate or prepend but wholly reload everything. Even if I touched dataSource with cloneWithRows statement, it didn't work for me. I tried to use 'new ListView', it starts to work! Would you suggest any negative sides for doing a such way?

Comment: @SungpahLee nothing really! What you have done is essentially the same as my snippet. I have `new ListView` in `getInitialState()` and you have the same in `constructor()`. So IMO I don't see any downside to this approach. However, other views are welcome. Also, you can directly replace the data instead of concatenation. Gist is important than these primitive operations. Remember, if you want to re-render the data, you only need to update the state.dataSource by calling `cloneWithRows(newdata)`.